# How did the Russians get moon rocks?

Tags: lunar-landing, russia, sample-return, luna

I've read somewhere that the Russians have moon rocks. How did they get them?

Comment: The Soviet Union were the first to do many things space related: put an object into space, put a creature into space, put a man into space, land a vehicle on the moon, land a robot on the moon, return things from the moon, etc., etc., ...

Comment: Luna-15 tried to be first with lunar rocks but failed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_15

Comment: I read somewhere (wait, I saw some at SpaceX), that the USA have moon rocks. How did they get them?

Comment: @DaveBoltman: through the Apollo program.

Comment: The main reason this is question is being asked is probably because the Soviet Union never landed a human being on the moon.  Before reading the accepted answer, I would have guessed that they simply acquired all of their moon rocks through the US.

Comment: @Octopus Luna 16 flew September 1970, so Apollo 11 beat them in "returning things from the moon".

Comment: @octopus Brother! I thought I was the only cephalopod!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The [USSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Union) flew three successful automated lunar sample return missions: [Luna 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_16), [Luna 20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_20) and [Luna 24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_24). The probes landed on the Moon, collected samples, and started a small rocket with the samples back to Earth. The returned mass was very small (101 g, 30 g and 170 g, respectively).

Comment: To complement - USSR also obtained samples of Apollo rocks in exchange for Luna stations samples. Source - livejournal post (in Russian language with massive inserted citations in English) : https://vakhnenko.livejournal.com/241952.html

Comment: As detailed in the Wikipedia articles @DarkDust cites, the Luna 16, 20, and 24 missions were flown in the early- to mid-1970's. Worth a look!

Comment: Thanks everyone that clears things up. I should have searched for `lunar rocks`

Comment: In addition, Nixon sent some of the Apollo moon rocks to the USSR. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_sample_displays ).

Comment: I've just asked [How did the Luna spacecraft collect samples of the moon and containerize them for return to Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34686/12102)